# do while code in VBA , finding a particular cell and i want to insert a blank row top of the cell...here i am attaching same data

Tags: excel, cell, vba

i have a file which contains lots of data , in column "C" i have below mentioned data:

```
1   Sales Order
2   minute
3   Two
4   second
5   Three
6   Sales Order
7   minute
8   Two
9   second
10  Three
11  Sales Order
12  minute
13  Two
14  second
15  Three
16  Sales Order
17  minute
18  Two
19  second
20  Three
```

and now i want to insert a blank row top of the Sales order column by using VBA code

Comment: Try recording a macro to do what you want and look at the code.

Comment: i know basic coding ....here my code ............Range("c5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Sales Order", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                Do While ActiveCell.Row = "Sales order  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDownActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
         Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    Loop
     
    
End Sub

Comment: Edit your question and place the code in there instead

Answer (score 0):

mattboy is correct, you MUST place your code within your question; it is impossible to read within a comment.

The code within the comment includes:

```
Do While ActiveCell.Row = "Sales order
```

The editor adds a trailing double quote if you omit it, so I do not understand how this could be your code.

Even if I correct your code, I do not understand what it is trying to do.

Your question says: "i want to insert a blank row top of the Sales order column".  You also say the data is in column C so I assume you want a blank cell under C1 with the rest of the column pushed down. Try:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  .Range("C2").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
End With
```